# Can I say like this: "All these (things) is evidence he was not there."?

Tags: word-choice, singular-vs-plural

I am not sure if "is", "are" or "represent" can be used in a sentence like this:

> "All these (things) **is/are/represent(s)** evidence he was not there."

UPDATE

Because I have received slightly conflicting answers I will try to make my initial question a bit more clear. There are four versions. Which one is correct?

> 1) All these **represent** evidence he was not there.
>
> 2) All these **represents** evidence he was not there.
>
> 3) All these **are** evidence he was not there.
>
> 4) All these **is** evidence he was not there.

Answer (score 2):

If you are pointing the things that repesent the evidence, or if they're already mentioned. Then *things* is optional. However, you don't need *is* or *are*

> "All these (things) represent evidence he was not there." -is grammatical

In an active simple present sentence, *is, are, be, and am* are known as *linking verbs*, A linking verb links a subject with a predicative adjective or a noun. *Represent* is a verb. So, you dont need one here.  You can read more about it on [Wikipedia](https://simple.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linking_verb)

You dont need an *s* after *represent* because it has to agree with the plural subject. You can read more about it  [here](http://www.grammarbook.com/grammar/subjectVerbAgree.asp)

Comment: So, "All these represent evidence" is the correct form and "All these is evidence" is incorrect but what about "All these are evidence"?

Comment: @RobertWerner it's incorrect too. *Evidence* is a mass(uncount) noun. So you must use a singular copula. *All this evidence is*.

Comment: The "are" from "All these are evidence" has to agree with "All these" or with "evidence"? In "All these represent evidence" it appears that "represent" agrees with "All these" not with "evidence".

Comment: @RobertWerner When you are using *there* or *all*. It has to agree with the complement. *"There are people.."*, *"There is a person.."*, *"All if these things are"*, *"All of this thing is..*". I know it's quite complicated, but you have to do your own research about this.

Comment: So, if "There are people" is correct then do I have to say "There are evidence" or "There is evidence"? The word "people" is like "evidence". However, for "people" it appears that an "are" should be used while for "evidence" an "is".

Comment: @RobertWerner No, as stated in my comment above, evidence is a mass noun, it's uncountable. It always takes a singular linking verb(is). I'm sorry, I think I should stop here, because this comment section is not extended for discussion. I recommend you to buy a book named *English Grammar for Dummies*. Ebooks is available online, look it up! :)

Comment: @user178049 - Wait, why do you think "All these are evidence" is incorrect?  It looks perfectly correct to me.

Comment: @stangdon I think the construction goes against the rule that a mass noun cannot be used plurally.

Comment: @user178049 The 'things' are plural, each thing is evidence, together they are evidence.

Comment: @user178049 - But this isn't using a mass noun plurally.  We're not saying "Evidence are", we're saying "These are".  [There are many, many examples of people using "These are evidence" in formal writing.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22these+are+evidence%22)

Answer (score 1):

> This is evidence. 
>   This represents evidence. 
>   This whole thing is evidence. 
>   This whole thing represents evidence.
>
> These are evidence. 
>   These represent evidence. 
>   All [of] these things are evidence. 
>   All [of] these things represent evidence.

The relevant rule is *subject/verb agreement*.   The verb's subject must agree with that verb, in both number and person.

The pronoun "this" is a singular third-person pronoun.   It agrees with the verb forms "is" and "represents".   The pronoun "these" is a plural third-person pronoun.   It agrees with the verb forms "are" and "represent".

The words "this" and "these" are also adjectives -- in fact, they are the same adjective.   Most adjectives do not have a grammatical number, meaning that adjectives themselves are rarely singular or plural.   However, "this" is the singular form and "these" is the plural.   For this reason, "this" agrees with "thing" and "these" agrees with "things".   We have an example of *adjective/noun agreement*.

As an extension, when "this" and "these" are used as pronouns, the grammatical number must match the number of whatever they represent.

There is one thing of which we have no example: *verb/argument agreement*.   Subjects must agree with their verbs.   Adjectives must agree with their nouns.   Pronouns must agree with their antecedents.   A verb's arguments are a separate matter.

In the sentence "These are evidence", there is no reason to expect "evidence" to agree with either "these" or "are".   The word "evidence" is the kind of argument that we call a complement.   Specifically, it is a predicate nominative subject complement.

The same thing happens in the sentence "These four people are my team."   Granted, "these four men" is plural, "my team" is singular, and both phrases represent the same thing.   They simply don't represent their referent in the same way.   It is just as natural to say "these four people are my team" as it is to say "my team is these four people".

Subject/verb agreement matters and is necessary.   Verb/argument agreement doesn't matter and is sometimes impossible.

Comment: From your answer I understand that the correct versions are: "1) All these represent evidence" and "3) All these are evidence" and the wrong forms are: "2) All these represents evidence" and "4) All these is evidence".